# Obtaining German residence permit when someone guarantees

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I've heard there is a possibility for obtaining residence permit in Germany if someone else guarantees to be caretaker, and shows enough proof their income is at least 2100 eur. per month.

What is the name of this type of residence permit?

What are the legal bounds for the person who agrees to be the "caretaker" in such a situation?

Comment: It's a translation but "caretaker" to me implies that the person being cared for is a dependent and may not be give permission to work AKA a minor or someone who is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Germany does not have a residency category which allows immigration to to care for an individual who is not related to you, and is not a minor. Proof of income is not specific to a category but a general requirement when applying for a residence permit, that you have sufficient income and/or financial resources

The German [Federal Office for Migration and Refugees](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Willkommen/Aufenthalt/WichtigeInformationen/wichtigeinformationen.html) outlines the purposes for which a resident permit may be obtained.

> The residence permit is issued for a limited period of time. It is granted to persons who:
>
> - would like to undergo training in Germany (sections 16-17 of the Residence Act [Aufenthaltsgesetz]),
> - would like to work in Germany (sections 18-21 of the Residence Act),
> - are entitled to remain in Germany for humanitarian or political reasons or under international law (sections 22-26 of the Residence Act),
> - are immigrating to Germany for family reasons (sections 27-36 of the Residence Act),
> - are foreign nationals and former Germans who would like to return to Germany (sections 37 and 38 of the Residence Act), or
> - hold a permanent right of residence in another Member State of the European Union (section 38a of the Residence Act).

The sections under which caretaker, or caregiver, would be applicable are:

- Family Reunification (Sections 28 and 29 – spouse, parent or underage child) – For family members who want to enter Germany in order to join family already living in Germany.
- Settlement Permit (Section 9) – This is the permanent residence permit, usually granted only after 5 years residence in Germany, and which requires a certain level of language proficiency.

The [Residence Act](https://germanlawarchive.iuscomp.org/?p=281), as it describes settlement for the purpose of care (or care and custody, or personal care), is referring to minor children and/or their parents. It is not a visa category or employment under which one can emigrate to Germany, for either short- or long-term residency.